# how to grep tomcat Pid in shell?

Tags: shell

I am using RHEL. I want grep PID of tomcat process by command

```
ps -ef | grep tomcat | awk '{print $2}'
```

my output is but I want is `28693` only.

```
root     12854  0.0  0.0 112652   968 pts/0    S+   01:12   0:00 grep --color=auto tomcat
root     28693  2.1 45.0 7479444 1629972 ?     Sl   Apr13  21:11 /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45//bin/jav
```

---

```
[root@uday  ~]#  ps -ef | grep tomcat | awk '{print $2}'
13240
28693
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pgrep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep),

```
pgrep tomcat
```

This would return only the PID of the process.

With `ps`

```
ps -ef | grep tomcat | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: thank you. as well this is also worked for me ps -ef | grep tomcat | awk 'NR==2 {print $2}'

Comment: What if the order of the output changes!

Answer (score 0):

`ps -ef | grep to[m]cat | awk '{print $2}'`

See the square brackets around one of the letters in the argument to the grep command? They are a regular expression. Square brackets in a regular expression mean "any one of those letters". So basically, you are looking for `to`, followed by any of the letters inside the square brackets (`m` only, here), followed by `cat`. Yes, this results to the same as writing `tomcat` literally, but it does prevent grep from finding it's own command line, because there it won't find the string `tomcat`, but `to[m]cat`. A little trick to prevent grep from matching itself.